# Access array in array elements

Tags: php

I have an array named 'users' in which I am storing some variables as you see below.I want to verify if the 'nume' (name) value already existing in this array is the same as the value introduced by a person in a search box. I've tried some methods but I haven't obtained the wanted result. I think it is something obvious I can't see at the moment.

EDIT : The image is the result of var_dump() of my code. I am using it for people to understand what I want to know.

[image: Here is the image]

Comment: Have you tried using a foreach loop? $exists=false; foreach ($array as $row) {if ($row['nume'] == $searchednume) { exists = true }}

Comment: @Namys I haven't tried it yet but I will now. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's simple, try that:

```
$searchValue = 'victor';
$index = array_search($searchValue, array_column($users, 'nume'));
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple. Thank you !